# Hadoop on Ubuntu 12.04.4 and mkdir: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, ubuntu-12.04, java

I have follow this how-to to configure hadoop on my ubuntu 12.04.4:

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

When I execute this command

```
 ./hadoop dfs -mkdir /In
```

I have this error:

```
 mkdir: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=hduser, access=WRITE, inode="":root:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x
```

In the how-to I execute the command:

```
 sudo chmod 750 /app/hadoop/tmp
```

If i give the chmod 777 the error don't change. I do not understand what the problem is.

P.s: The only difference between How-To and my configuration is that in the how-to I have hadoop-env.sh like this:

```
 # The java implementation to use.  Required.
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

In my configuration I have:

```
# The java implementation to use.  Required.
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
```

because i use openjdk.

Another problem, if i give the command ./start-all.sh i have these output:

```
 Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

 starting namenode, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-ubuntu.out
 hduser@localhost's password: 
 localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-ubuntu.out
 hduser@localhost's password: 
 localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-ubuntu.out
 starting jobtracker, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-jobtracker-ubuntu.out
 hduser@localhost's password: 
 localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-ubuntu.out
```

I do not understand why he asks me several times pasword.

If i execute command  ./stop-all.s i have this output:

```
 Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

 no jobtracker to stop
 hduser@localhost's password: 
 localhost: stopping tasktracker
 no namenode to stop
 hduser@localhost's password: 
 localhost: no datanode to stop
 hduser@localhost's password: 
 localhost: no secondarynamenode to stop
```

It's normale?

Comment: Did u create new user with name hduser ?

Comment: are you able to passwordless ssh to localhost? That could be reason why you are being asked for password every time. What do logs for namenode show?

Comment: How i can enable passwordless ssh to localhost? And where i can find the logs?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create new hdfs directories you should have dedicated hadoop user with appropriate privileges. Follow the following to resolve your problem

```
$ sudo addgroup hadoop
$ sudo adduser --ingroup hadoop hduser

$ cd /usr/local
$ sudo tar xzf hadoop-1.0.3.tar.gz
$ sudo mv hadoop-1.0.3 hadoop
$ sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop hadoop
```

Comment: try this '''./hadoop dfs -mkdir /app/hadoop/tmp/In'''